# How can I make the browser not parse html in an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe, content-type

I have a webpage where I stream data by Ajax (using readyState 3 etc.). This works fine on most browsers, but on IE7-9 it seems like I can't read the text received so far even when readyState is 3 (although I've read you can do it in IE9 but it just doesn't work when I try it..).

Instead, for a fallback, I use an invisible iframe which requests the data and then I read the data from there - the problem is the data, while it is JSON-encoded, also contains actual HTML inside. I need the data to remain the way it is, but since it's inside an iframe, the HTML gets parsed by the browser.

Basically, all I want is for the browser not to parse the HTML in that data. I initially thought this could be done easily by using the right content-type, but so far it doesn't seem to work (I tried application/octet-stream for example).

I figure I can solve this by putting the entire data in a comment, but i'd rather not do that.
What's the easiest way to prevent the browser from parsing this HTML in this case? Or am I simply using the wrong content-type?

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `readyState` be 4 when completed?

Comment: Did you try the `text/plain` mime type?

Comment: freefaller - yes it should, but i'm accessing data before the request is complete. Note that this isn't really relevant for the question though - I only mentioned it as an intro.

Anish - yes i have, didn't help unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<xmp>` tag is deprecated and is not part of the standard anymore. `<textarea>` is certainly an option if speed is of the essence in your case. The third option is of course to HTML encode your content before sending it to the client using whatever server technology you're using and using `decode()` on the client to get the HTML.

Comment: Please consider visiting the [markdown help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for assistance with formatting inline code.

Comment: @David Thomas was typing on the iPhone :) can't find the damn reverse single quote.

Comment: @Strelok I don't have an iPhone but, if it helps, the character is called a backtick.

Comment: I seem to recall that if you press and hold the `'` button, then it shows a pop-up with four alternative quotes, one of which is the backtick. =)

Comment: @John H I think the character is actually called a grave accent, but that doesn't help me type it .....oh `and I just found how to type it on the iPhone, yay`. You have to hold down the single quote character until the additional characters appear. Edit: thanks David, just found it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use <xmp> tags, the tag tells the browser that your content is CDDATA and ignores all the HTML tags in there.

<xmp><font color="red"><b>My data here</b></font></xmp>

Will print:

<font color="red"><b>My data here</b></font>

Comment: Thank you, but I've read XMP tags aren't cross-browser, and is not standard HTML. Right now I'm using <textarea>, but I'd rather avoid that as well.